# Is there any way of not creating temp variable for push_back()?

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.push_back(Foo());
```

Does this create a temp variable for Foo, or does this work like emplace_back()?

Answer (score 2):

`Foo()` creates a temporary, although in theory compiler is allowed to optimize it away due to [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

You can use [`vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which

> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed through `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container.

Comment: I am only wondering if my code will create a temp variable, that's it

Comment: Did you edit the question or did I overlook existing `emplace_back` reference? Anyway, `Foo()` creates a temporary, although compiler is allowed to optimize it away.